# Core Data Entity/Attribute migration is giving error, "Unacceptable type of value for attribute"

Tags: ios, core-data

I am very new to Core Data migration.

I have a Core Data entity called "User" which contains an attribute called "userId".  At the moment, this attribute is of type Integer64, and I need to now change this to String.  When I create a new version of the data model, and use the newer version in my application, I am able to use the new version of the data model as long as it is a blank application with no additional data entered.  However, when I enter new data into my application, and then try to migrate the application to the new version of the Data Model, I get the error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "userId"; desired type = NSString; given type = __NSCFNumber; value = 12345
```

I realize that by simply deleting the application from the simulator/device will resolve this issue, but in doing so, I will lose the data that I have just recently entered, and I do not want that.  I want to be able to migrate the application to the new version of the Data Model INCLUDING the existing data that has already been entered into the application.  How can I do this?

### Edit

These are the steps I have taken in order to do the migration:

1. Create a new version of my data model.
2. In the new version, I change the type of my attribute from Integer64 to String
3. I set the current version in the File Inspector to the latest version of the data model where I made the change.
4. I change my code to treat the attribute as an NSString instead of an NSNumber.//I have skipped this step as well but the result is still the same.
5. I run my application again, and that is when I get the error that I mention above.

On a side note: when I put in this line of code:

```
NSLog(@"which version? %@", [[self managedObjectModel] versionIdentifiers]);
```

My output is:

```
which version? {(
    ""
)}
```

Not sure why I am getting this.

Comment: Need more info about how you're doing this. I'd expect either "...model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store" or else "Can't find or automatically infer mapping model..." with common migration failures. I'm not sure where that error comes from.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment.  I've added an update in my question explaining how I got the error.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, i am getting same issue, please share if you solved